How do I get the LogicalName from query and store into variables using sqlcmd
I want to write a PowerShell script to automatically restore database backups when I need it. But I'm having some trouble with it because when I restore it, I don't restore it to its original name, usually to a different name.
And the problem I am facing is getting the logical name from my backup. I got this query that can retrieve the logical name, but I cannot seem to figure out how to extract that name from the results.
$serverName = "MY-PC"
$backupFolder = "D:\DatabaseBackup"
$userName = "sa"
$password = "123"

$logicalNameData = ""
$logicalNameLog = ""

$query = @"
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    [LogicalName] varchar(128),
    [PhysicalName] varchar(128),
    [Type] varchar,
    [FileGroupName] varchar(128),
    [Size] varchar(128),
    [MaxSize] varchar(128),
    [FileId]varchar(128),
    [CreateLSN]varchar(128),
    [DropLSN]varchar(128),
    [UniqueId]varchar(128),
    [ReadOnlyLSN]varchar(128),
    [ReadWriteLSN]varchar(128),
    [BackupSizeInBytes]varchar(128),
    [SourceBlockSize]varchar(128),
    [FileGroupId]varchar(128),
    [LogGroupGUID]varchar(128),
    [DifferentialBaseLSN]varchar(128),
    [DifferentialBaseGUID]varchar(128),
    [IsReadOnly]varchar(128),
    [IsPresent]varchar(128),
    [TDEThumbprint]varchar(128),
    [SnapshotUrl]varchar(128)
)
DECLARE @Path varchar(1000)='D:/DatabaseBackup/ISEM10NAYEER.bak'
DECLARE @LogicalNameData varchar(128),@LogicalNameLog varchar(128)
INSERT INTO @table
EXEC('
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM DISK=''' +@Path+ '''
   ')

SET @LogicalNameData=(SELECT LogicalName
FROM @Table
WHERE Type='D')
SET @LogicalNameLog=(SELECT LogicalName
FROM @Table
WHERE Type='L')

SELECT @LogicalNameData, @LogicalNameLog
"@

$returnData = & sqlcmd -S $serverName -U $userName -P $password -Q $query

How do I extract the values and insert it into $logicalNameData and $logicalNameLog?

Does this answer your question? How do you run a SQL Server query from PowerShell?
